# How to have multiple predictions in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

A model I am training has two separate FFNNs for an inputted query and document. The loss function is a similarity between the outputs of these two FFNNs.

I would then like to use these separate FFNNs to encode a bunch of queries and a bunch of documents, separately.

Does Keras have a way to have multiple prediction modes, which are different from just calculating the loss?

If it makes a difference, I am using the Tensorflow backend.

Comment: You can use function model. It support [multi-input and multi-output models](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models).